# Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView w/ Selection="Multiple" for only 2nd level or lower

Tags: c#, winui-3

Given I have a (WinUI3) TreeView like below.

```xml
<TreeView SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

Is there a way to set it up so that the non-root level child nodes are not selectable?  So basically the root level items don't have a checkbox.

Comment: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.* is for UWP only. Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.* is for WinUI3 only, so which one is it?

Comment: I used a winui-3 tag to indicate that my question was related to WinUI3.

Comment: Why does your question include Windows.UI.Xaml then? You can't mix both technologies at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The `TreeViewSelectionMode` values are `None`, `Single`, and `Multiple`. Whether you want to implement the effect that a TreeView with Multi-selection enabled?

[image]

If so, I suggest you could refer to the  [TreeViewPage.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/TreeViewPage.xaml) and [TreeViewPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/TreeViewPage.xaml.cs)

Comment: I did.  I had to use a DataTemplateSelector with various data templates to achieve this.  And I had to use my own selection mechanism instead of the built-in one.

Comment: You could try to set `Visibility` property to make the checkbox visible for the root-level node. And then you could try to set the `IsChecked` property of the CheckBox to `indeterminate`. Refer to the Doc:[Check boxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky but should work:

```cs
private void TreeViewControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not TreeView treeViewControl)
    {
        return;
    }

    IEnumerable<TreeViewItem> rootItems = treeViewControl
        .FindDescendants()
        .OfType<TreeViewItem>();

    foreach (TreeViewItem item in rootItems)
    {
        if (item.FindDescendant<CheckBox>() is not CheckBox checkBox)
        {
            continue;
        }

        checkBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        checkBox.IsHitTestVisible = false;

        checkBox.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(
            CheckBox.VisibilityProperty,
            (_, _) =>
            {
                checkBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            });
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

`FindDescendants` comes from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) NuGet package.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to `FindDescendants` extension method.